# Type 1083: Syntax error: package is unexpected

Tags: actionscript-3, class, package

So, I got this .as file that is called, let say, class A.

class A inside has other 2 classes, class B and class C, and the only class that is inside a package is class A. And it throws that error.

I downloaded this as an example, and it should work, however Flash Builder 4.6 doesn't like it.

The structure of the as file is like this:

imports
variables
class B
class C
package
  public class A
/package

Btw, I'm using Flash Builder not Flash CC.

Update, posting code:

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.WarpClient;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.listener.ConnectionRequestListener;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.listener.NotificationListener;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.listener.RoomRequestListener;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.listener.ZoneRequestListener;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.messages.Chat;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.messages.LiveResult;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.messages.LiveRoom;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.messages.LiveUser;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.messages.Lobby;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.messages.MatchedRooms;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.messages.Move;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.messages.Room;
import com.shephertz.appwarp.types.ResultCode;

import flash.utils.ByteArray;

var APIKEY:String = "key";
var SECRETEKEY:String = "secretkey";
var Connected:Boolean = false;
var INITIALIZED:Boolean = false;
var client:WarpClient;
var roomID:String;
var State:int = 0;
var User:String;

class connectionListener implements ConnectionRequestListener
{   
    private var connectFunc:Function;

    public function connectionListener(f:Function)
    {
        connectFunc = f;
    }

    public function onConnectDone(res:int):void
    {
        if(res == ResultCode.success)
        {
            Connected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Connected = false;
        }

        connectFunc(res);
    }

    public function onDisConnectDone(res:int):void
    {
        Connected = false;
    }
}

class roomListener implements RoomRequestListener
{
    private var connectFunc:Function;
    private var joinFunc:Function;

    public function roomListener(f:Function,f1:Function)
    {
        connectFunc = f;
        joinFunc = f1;
    }

    public function onSubscribeRoomDone(event:Room):void
    {
        if(State == 2)
            joinFunc();
        else
            connectFunc();
    }
    public function onUnsubscribeRoomDone(event:Room):void
    {

    }
    public function onJoinRoomDone(event:Room):void
    {
        if(event.result == ResultCode.resource_not_found)
        {
            if(State == 1)
            {
                State = 3;
            }
            client.createRoom("room","admin",2,null);
        }
        else if(event.result == ResultCode.success)
        {
            if(State == 1)
            {
                State = 2;  
            }
            roomID = event.roomId;
            client.subscribeRoom(roomID);
        }
    }
    public function onLeaveRoomDone(event:Room):void
    {
        client.unsubscribeRoom(roomID);
    }
    public function onGetLiveRoomInfoDone(event:LiveRoom):void
    {

    }
    public function onSetCustomRoomDataDone(event:LiveRoom):void
    {

    }
    public function onUpdatePropertyDone(event:LiveRoom):void
    {

    }

    public function onLockPropertiesDone(result:int):void
    {

    }
    public function onUnlockPropertiesDone(result:int):void
    {

    }
    public function onUpdatePropertiesDone(event:LiveRoom):void
    {

    }
}

class zoneListener implements ZoneRequestListener
{   
    public function onCreateRoomDone(event:Room):void
    {
        roomID = event.roomId;
        client.joinRoom(roomID);
    }

    public function onDeleteRoomDone(event:Room):void
    {

    }

    public function onGetLiveUserInfoDone(event:LiveUser):void
    {

    }

    public function onGetAllRoomsDone(event:LiveResult):void
    {

    }
    public function onGetOnlineUsersDone(event:LiveResult):void
    {

    }
    public function onSetCustomUserInfoDone(event:LiveUser):void
    {

    }

    public function onGetMatchedRoomsDone(event:MatchedRooms):void
    {

    }
}

class notifylistener implements NotificationListener
{
    private var joinFunc:Function;
    private var msgFunc:Function;
    private var leaveFunc:Function;

    public function notifylistener(f:Function)
    {
        joinFunc = f;
    }

    public function msgListener(f:Function,f1:Function):void
    {
        msgFunc = f;
        leaveFunc = f1;
    }

    public function onRoomCreated(event:Room):void
    {

    }
    public function onRoomDestroyed(event:Room):void
    {

    }
    public function onUserLeftRoom(event:Room, user:String):void
    {
        if(user != User)
        {
            leaveFunc();
        }
    }
    public function onUserJoinedRoom(event:Room, user:String):void
    {
        if(State == 3)
            joinFunc();
    }
    public function onUserLeftLobby(event:Lobby, user:String):void
    {

    }
    public function onUserJoinedLobby(event:Lobby, user:String):void
    {

    }
    public function onChatReceived(event:Chat):void
    {
        if(event.sender != User)
        {
            var obj:Object = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(event.chat);
            msgFunc(obj);
        }
    }
    public function onUpdatePeersReceived(update:ByteArray):void
    {

    }
    public function onUserChangeRoomProperty(room:Room, user:String,properties:Object):void
    {

    }
    public function onPrivateChatReceived(sender:String, chat:String):void
    {

    }
    public function onUserChangeRoomProperties(room:Room, user:String,properties:Object, lockTable:Object):void
    {

    }
    public function onMoveCompleted(move:Move):void
    {

    }
}

package
{
    import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
    import com.shephertz.appwarp.WarpClient;

    public class AppWarp
    {   
        public static var _roomlistener:roomListener;
        public static var _zonelistener:zoneListener;
        public static var _notifylistener:notifylistener;
        public static var _connectionlistener:connectionListener;

        private static function generateRandomString(strlen:Number):String{
            var chars:String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            var num_chars:Number = chars.length - 1;
            var randomChar:String = "";
            for (var i:Number = 0; i < strlen; i++){
                randomChar += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * num_chars));
            }
            return randomChar;
        }

        public static function connect(f:Function):void
        {
            if(INITIALIZED == false)
            {
                WarpClient.initialize(APIKEY, SECRETEKEY);
                client = WarpClient.getInstance();
                INITIALIZED = true;
            }

            if(Connected == false)
            {
                _connectionlistener = new connectionListener(f);
                client.setConnectionRequestListener(_connectionlistener);
                User = generateRandomString(16);
                client.connect(User);
            }
            else
                f(0);
        }

        public static function join(f1:Function, f2:Function):void
        {
            _roomlistener = new roomListener(f1,f2);
            _zonelistener = new zoneListener();
            _notifylistener = new notifylistener(f2);

            client.setRoomRequestListener(_roomlistener);
            client.setZoneRequestListener(_zonelistener);
            client.setNotificationListener(_notifylistener);

            State = 1;
            client.joinRoomInRange(1,1,true);
        }

        public static function leave():void
        {
            client.leaveRoom(roomID);
        }

        public static function begin(f:Function, f1:Function, dir:int, x:int, y:int):void
        {
            _notifylistener.msgListener(f, f1);
            send(0,dir,x,y);
        }

        public static function move(dir:int,x:int,y:int):void
        {
            send(1,dir,x,y);
        }

        public static function eat(dir:int,x:int,y:int):void
        {
            send(2,dir,x,y);
        }

        public static function send(type:int,dir:int,x:int,y:int):void
        {
            if(Connected == true)
            {
                var obj:Object = new Object();
                obj.type = type;
                obj.dir = dir;
                obj.x = x;
                obj.y = y;

                client.sendChat(com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.encode(obj));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your class code? Is not clear in your question.

Comment: In class AppWarp which's the package???

Comment: Scroll down, 4/5 the length of the file, aprox.

Comment: This is.... package
{
    import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
    import com.shephertz.appwarp.WarpClient; there's no package explicited

    public class AppWarp

Comment: I don't get it, the public class AppWarp is inside the package.

Comment: Yes, but the package must be specified. Is It in the default package?

Comment: Of course, its default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to place the package keyword at the very beginning of the .as file, otherwise an error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You can only define one class in a package in a file. You can define other classes outside the package, but I don't think that is a good idea as I have observed that in some versions of compiler you have to place it at the beginning and in some at the end. Sometimes, it won't work in anyway.

A better way is to define different classes for each listener in different files. You can use the same package name.

I would recommend creating a single class to listen to all listeners by implementing all base listener classes.

For e.g.

```
//listener.as
package
{
    public class Listener implements ConnectionRequestListener, RoomRequestListener, NotificationListener
    {
    }
}
```